# AspectJ LTW (weaving) not working with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj

I'm on `Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE` - `Java 11` - **Fat JAR**

Following the documentation, I have:

added the required dependencies to the Gradle build

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.2'
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.2'
```

enabled `LoadTimeWeaving`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class MyApplication { ... }
```

provided the `aop.xml` under `META-INF`

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="my.base.package.*" />
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="my.base.package.spring.aop.MyAspects" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

created the new `@Aspect` class

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspects {
    @Around("methodsToBeProfiled()")
    public Object profile(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        final var sw = new StopWatch(getClass().getSimpleName());
        try {
            sw.start(pjp.getSignature().getName());
            return pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            sw.stop();
            System.out.println(sw.prettyPrint());
        }
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* my.base.package.other.MyClass.*(..))")
    public void methodsToBeProfiled() {}
}
```

added the Jar for instrumentation

```
-javaagent:/home/myuser/spring-instrument-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
```

Log, which as you see, show `MyAspects` as recognized

```
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.2 built on Wednesday Oct 24, 2018 at 15:43:33 GMT
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info register classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2c13da15
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info using configuration /home/edoardo/IdeaProjects/scheduler/scheduler-engine/out/production/resources/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info using configuration file:/home/edoardo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/5.1.5.RELEASE/3bb95e05b646ef93e2a4cf0b600924c2979fc723/spring-aspects-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info register aspect my.base.package.spring.aop.MyAspects
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info register aspect org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info register aspect org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.JtaAnnotationTransactionAspect
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info deactivating aspect 'org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.JtaAnnotationTransactionAspect' as it requires type 'javax.transaction.Transactional' which cannot be found on the classpath
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info register aspect org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info register aspect org.springframework.cache.aspectj.JCacheCacheAspect
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info deactivating aspect 'org.springframework.cache.aspectj.JCacheCacheAspect' as it requires type 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheAspectSupport' which cannot be found on the classpath
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] info deactivating aspect 'org.springframework.cache.aspectj.JCacheCacheAspect' as it requires type 'javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult' which cannot be found on the classpath
[AppClassLoader@2c13da15] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
```

---

However `MyAspects` is never instantiated (so no debug), and methods are not being weaved with my aspect code.

Did I miss something?

---

Edit: seems both Jars, `aspectjweaver` and `spring-instrument` are required as agents. Is this normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need the `aspectjweaver` agent jar. You don't need `spring-instrument` (ever for a fat jar - AFAIK it was used in app servers to work around some historical issues with their class loaders). You also don't need to `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` (also an app server feature, redundant if you control the agent). Also (minor niggle) `aspectjrt` is a transitive dependency of `aspectjweaver`, so you don't need both. So you have it working it seems, even though you have done more work than you needed. Sample Spring Boot apps with various weaving options: [here](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-aspectj).

Comment: Thank you! However it seems that removing the `spring-instrument` agent causes LTW to stop working. I did a lot of tests yesterday; keeping only the `aspectjweaver` agent, plus using a Bean `return Aspects.aspectOf(MyAspects.class)` (as per GitHub example) throws a `NoSuchMethodException - aspectOf` on `MyAspects`

Comment: But then I don't understand, what's the use of `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`? Are you saying it is valid only for application servers such a WebLogic or Tomcat?

Comment: Yes, `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` is intended primarily for use in an app server. It works in tandem with the `spring-instrument` agent, so if you don't use one, you won't need the other. You *could* use them outside an app server, but there really isn't any point if you control the agent path. The `NoSuchMethodException` indicates that you haven't successfully woven the aspect class. Check your config files.

Comment: Some more info: `aspectjweaver.jar` is a superset of `aspectjrt.jar`. Transitive dependency or not, you never need the latter if using the former already. The runtime JAR is needed for compile-time woven code, but then you do not need the weaving agent. So it is either one or the other.

Comment: `aspectjweaver` does not have any dependencies, according to its [pom](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/jar).

Comment: True, but that's a nitpick. Actually `aspectjrt` is packaged inside the weaver jar, I think.

Comment: @DaveSyer, which is why I said it is a superset. The weaver contains all classes from the runtime.